# What is the best Azure function type to create when I need to call it from my web app?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a web app (website) and on a specific event I want to call and run an Azure function.

**QUESTION** - What's the best function type to use?

I know there are multiple Azure functions types:
HTTP trigger, Timer trigger, Event Hubs trigger, Blob Storage trigger, Cosmos DB trigger, Event Grid trigger, Queue Storage trigger, Generic webhook, Service Bus trigger

FYI - I don't really want to create any additional resources like a queue or a blob or a service bus just for this function.

Comment: Use HTTP trigger

Comment: On a specific event in your webapp, you want to execute some code, what does it do - is it a long running one, do you want it's result or you want to just initiate it ? Based on these you need to choose HTTP trigger or durable function, etc.

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran What's a durable function?

Comment: My function needs to loop through a list of objects fetched from a db, and for each item in the list call a 3rd party service (Stripe) to make a transfer, then get the transfer result back from Stripe and save the results in my db. There could potentially be hundreds of these calls per function call, so offloading it from my web app is most likely needed. Depending on the list size it could potentially take 20-30 seconds or longer to run.

Comment: You could create a HTTP trigger function which kick starts a durable function with `fan-out/fan-in` pattern, see this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#application-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

> don't really want to create any additional resources like a queue or a blob or a service bus just for this function.

Then you can use Azure Http Trigger Function. In Function you can send the list objects as the body of request or you can even fetch the details from DB.

Inside the function you can loop through each item in the list and call the 3 rd party service(Stripe) and then get back the details from that. Http trigger allows offloading too.

I would use queue trigger/ Service Bus trigger in which i would get messages into queue and then get it to function, but you can also use HTTP trigger Function too.

In Functions you can use Input and Output Binding which should help your Application.

[image]

Comment: What's the easiest way to call the http trigger function from my web app (website) with C#? I can't seem to find anything by Googling it.

Comment: You can use HttpClient for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0

Comment: @user1186050  a HTTP trigger function is just like any other webservice or REST service that you could call.  From C#, you could use `HttpClient` to call it, or use some packages like `RestSharp`

Comment: Yeah you are right! @Anand Sowmithiran